# Django CMS FieldError: Local field 'created_by' in class 'PageUser' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'User'

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I have an existing django 1.9 application on python 3.5 and I'm trying to bring django cms into it. Right now, I'm following the manual install instructions here: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/how_to/install.html

I want to use the existing postgres db for storing cms data. Right now, all I've done is add the cms apps to INSTALLED_APPS as well as the middleware and the templates, all in the settings file. When I launch my app I get the FieldError:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'created_by' in class 'PageUser' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'User'
```

I ran through this http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/reference/configuration.html#custom-user-requirements and made sure our custom User was inheriting properly and had the right fields and methods.

Our custom User model does inherit from a custom mixin that adds a created_by to the user model.

I can't find a workaround that solves this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the error that you are facing?

Comment: I added the error to the body above.

Comment: Check the answer I posted. I hope it helps you solve your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should rename the field. Something like this

```
class PageUser(User):
    page_user_created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
                                             related_name="created_users", db_column='created_by')
```

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/4225)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. That solution looks like it's a suggestion for them to change their implementation. cms has to load after our app loads our custom User model. I've tried creating a custom PageUser class, but it won't load in the right order to get around this issue. Right now we're leaning toward renaming our created_by, but that's a big ask in our app.